# Доступ для записи значения в определённом индексе в string.

Tags: c#, строки

```
string a = "abc";
a[0] = 'z'; // Ошибка! ... доступ только для чтения.
```

Вопрос: можно ли сделать доступ для записи в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строки в C# неизменяемы, так что напрямую изменить строку нельзя. При любой операции со строкой создаётся новый объект. Вы можете конвертировать строку в массив `char`'ов, произвести замену, затем из массива снова собрать строку:

```
string str = "qwerty";
char[] chars = str.ToCharArray();
chars[3] = 'A';
str = new string(chars);
```

Ещё вы можете использовать класс [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx). В нём переопределён оператор индексации (`[]`):

```
string str = "qwerty";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb[3] = 'A';
str = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет.

Пользуйтесь функциями substr, например.